# RegExp NOT match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this RegExp

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/(^((?!(\n|[0-9])).)*$)/mg,'');
```

That replaces everything except digits and new lines.
    The problem is that if I have a string like this: *word_and_numbers123123123* the RegExp doesn't replace the letters.

Every thing

```
/(^((?!(HERE)).)*$)/
```

is, as far as i am concerned, **NOT** removed.
Im simply using `\n|[0-9]`
Where "`HERE`" is, so, full RegExp:

```
/(^((?!(\n|[0-9])).)*$)/
```

But the problem, is once again, that it, the RegExp, doesn't remove `%$word` in for example this string: `%$word_2143234`

Comment: Your regexp says that the string must not contain digits and newline characters inits entirety (^ to $), so any digit anywhere in the string kills the match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I have misunderstood. Why not simply do the replace without the negative look ahead?

this should replace

> everything except digits and new lines.

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/([^\r\n\d]+)/g,'');
```